# run two for loops in one line when first glob fails

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, glob

I am trying to run this:

```
for file in a?; do echo $file; done; for file in b?; do echo $file; done
```

both loops run (intended) if there are files that match `a?` and `b?`

But if there are no `a?` files then I get this error

```
zsh: no matches found: a?
```

and the second loop never runs.

How can I always run both loops?

I realised I can put `a?(N)` the `(N)` glob parameter to skip the error, but I still want the `no matches found` output for the first loop if no matches were found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `zsh`:

```
unsetopt nomatch    
for f in a?; do [[ -e "$f" ]] && echo "$f" || echo "no matches found"; done

setopt nomatch
for f in b?; do echo "$f"; done
```

[zsh `nomatch` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Description-of-Options)

Answer (score -1):

Since you just echo the file names, there is no need for a loop.

```
a_files=( a?(N) )
if (( ${#a_files} > 0 ))
then
  # We have at least one entry starting with 'a'
  echo $a_files
  echo b?(N)
fi
```

Assuming you do need a nested loop, because you want to process something with the a and the b files, you can do a

```
a_files=( a?(N) )
if (( ${#a_files} > 0 ))
then
  # We have at least one entry starting with 'a'
  for a_file in $a_files
  do
      echo $a_file
      for b_file in b?(N)
      do
         do_something_with $a_file $b_file
      done
  done
fi
```

UPDATE:

Running two loops in sequence, but guarantteed that each loop is run at least once:

```
a_loop_entered=0
for file in a?(N) .
do
  if [[ $file != . || $a_loop_entered==0 ]]
    a_loop_entered=1
    # Now do your loop body. 
  fi
done
```

Comment: obviously my question was just a tiny example, the real command I want to run is not simply echoing the file names. And I think you misunderstood the question bc I don't want to run a nested loop.

Comment: But you have two sets of files - starting with a and starting with b - and you want to execute your command for each combinations of these sets? This is exactly what the nested loops do.

Comment: I don't want to process the command for each combination. Read the question, the logic of my example code snippet is intended. I want to run two distinct loops in sequence.